# Yii 2 Quicker way to access controller from view

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2

So in Yii 1, in the view file you could access the Controller's properties / actions using `$this->action()` or `$this->property`.

In Yii 2, the only way I can see this possible is using `Yii::$app->controller->property` or `Yii::$app->controller->action()`. I am one for not wanting to write more code than is necessary, so I was wondering if there's a shorter method of doing it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For view controller is basically "context" where render of this view was called.

There is special property to get current related controller from view and it's called exactly like this: `context`.

Example: `$this->context`

**Official docs:**

- [View context](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#$context-detail)

Comment: This works perfectly and seems a little more intuitive than `Yii::$app->controller;`

Comment: This is also good if you're developing widgets and want to call the main widget component from the widget view file.

Answer (score 0):

`\Yii::$app->controller` in indeed the only "real" way to do so.

There is a way of writing a bit less, dunno if it is worth the effort:

```
public function actionWhatever() 
{
    return $this->render('view', ['controller' => $this]);
}
```

Then in your view you have a `$controller`-variable.